# django View Does Not Exist

Tags: django, django-views

I had a few views that were working, but now that I've added a new view it no longer works and I keep getting the error `ViewDoesNotExist`.

Traceback:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 101.request.path_info)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve 300.sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve 
209. return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback  216. self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper 27.result = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable 101.(lookup_view, mod_name))

  Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /login/
  Exception Value: Could not import owners.views.login_request. View does not exist in module owners.views.
```

Any additional information / pointers on what I may be doing wrong would be helpful.

myview

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = Loginform(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            site_user = authenticate(username= username,password = password )

            if site_user is not None:
                login(request,site_user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
            else:
               return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    else:
        '''user not subinting show loging form'''
        form = Loginform()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('login.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and my url looks like this

```
(r'^login/$','owners.views.login_request'),
```

i have about 70views and its all gone down only the '/' works

Comment: share your `urls.py`, and `views.py`

Comment: Please share your code. Do you have the path correctly specified in urls.py? theres a '.' on the end.
"Could not import owners.views.login_request."

Comment: Can you post your entire URLs file? And can you clarify your last line `i have about 70views and its all gone down only the '/' works`. You are saying that this is not the only view that does not work, correct? Are you sure this import is correct `owners.views.login_request`? Can you post that import and your file structure?

Comment: yes Dan all my views are down its just the home page that works django is not importing my views what could be causing this

Comment: Post your entire URL file, including the imports please. Also please outline your folder structure. The issue is most likely in your `view` import in your URL file at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the imports the models got confused as they imported from all over the place so i made a central app that managed every thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of the view function is as the same one passed in the urls. Otherwise, please pass the view function and your urls, yes all of the urls file :)